# how to use wordpress is_email() function in external file

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm coding an external php script that will be called from ajax in one of my WP page.
I want this script to be able to use wordpress functions. 
This is what I've done so far:

```
require_once( $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/wp-load.php' );
```

this allows me to access `$wpdb` object. Good. But I also want to use `is_email()` function and perhaps other native WP functions. 
Right now I'm getting `"Call to undefined function is_email()..."` Fatal error.
Any advice appreciated

Comment: Have you included the file containing those functions?

Comment: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_email

Did you even bother looking ?

Comment: Why can't you just use filter_var with the FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL flag?

Comment: Jay and LuckyBurger yes I did try including wp-includes/formatting.php file, didn't help.
@David Harris I could do that but while I was reading about email validation I found a lot of comments advising not to use this due to false negative results.

After all I decided to go with the solution proposed by mudasobwa.

Thank you all

Comment: And yet if anyone knows the answer on how to include all wp functions to external file i'd appreciate this info...

Comment: WP's is_email function is not RFC compliant.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it wrong. WP is glad to provide the requested functionality for you. You should declare the handler in your plugin/theme `functions.php` file and register a handler for `wp_ajax_my_action` (the example is taken from WP Codex):

```
<?php 
add_action( 'wp_ajax_my_action', 'my_action_callback' );
function my_action_callback() {
    global $wpdb; // this is how you get access to the database
    $whatever = intval( $_POST['whatever'] );
    $whatever += 10;
    echo $whatever;

    wp_die(); // this is required to terminate immediately 
              // and return a proper response
}
```

[More info](http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins).

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps not the most elegant way but at least it worked for me.

in functions.php

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'localize_scripts');
  function localize_scripts() {
  wp_localize_script('jquery', 'urls', array( 'ajaxurl' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php') )); 
}
```

inside the javascript

```
$.ajax({
    url: urls.ajaxurl,
    data: {
        'action':'my_function',
        'otherData': someString //variable
          },
    cache: false,
    success: function() {},
    error: function() {}
});
```

and again in functions.php

```
function my_function() {

  // The $_REQUEST contains all the data sent via ajax
  if ( isset($_REQUEST) ) { 
    $someString = $_REQUEST['otherData'];
    echo $someString;
    // Always die in functions echoing ajax content
    die();
  }
}

add_action( 'wp_ajax_my_function', 'my_function' );
```